# How to insert the whole matched text in the replacement in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to add a string (`A`) after all specific other strings (`bbc`). So, I match `bbc` and want to replace it with itself with `A` appended (`'aabbcc' => 'aabbcAc'`).

Is there a replacement back-reference that gets substituted with the whole match?

`$0` doesn't seem to work – its content is always "-e", for some reason:

`$ echo 'aabbcc' | perl -p -e 's/bbc/$0A/g'
aa-eAc`

Comment: The reference to the whole match in perl is `$&` not `$0`

Comment: Thanks! I tried `\&` and '$MATCH' (which didn't work) but somehow missed '$&'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$&`, see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$&

```
$ echo 'aabbcc' | perl -p -e 's/bbc/$&A/g'
aabbcAc
```